# How to set UIToolbar height on iOS 13

Tags: ios, ios13

I am working on supporting iOS 13 in my app and one of the problems I'm facing is that toolbars are now twice as tall on X variant phones. In the [UIToolbar Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitoolbar?language=objc)
there is now a compactAppearance and standardAppearance but those don't seem to control the size of the Toolbar. The fact that those properties exist makes me assume that there is a way to set a toolbar to be compact. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Are you using a tabbar by any chance? see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120322

Comment: Also see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/?time=444 around 7:30

Comment: I am using a tab bar so it sounds like that is the issue. I'll wait for the final release of Xcode 11 and see if they fix the issue

Comment: You can play around with the appearance ```if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        UIToolbarAppearance *appearance = [[UIToolbarAppearance alloc] init];
        [appearance configureWithTransparentBackground];
        appearance.backgroundImageContentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        
        [UIToolbar appearance].standardAppearance = appearance;
        [UIToolbar appearance].compactAppearance = appearance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to be fixed on iOS 13.1 beta 2
see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120322